# Unit test for service with many dependencies Angular

Tags: angular, unit-testing

I'd like to know how to test the following Service, which has two dependency in constructor.

I don't know how to create environment for test, how to implement **MatDiaglog** in a test.

Should I make fake requests for test this functions?
In general, what is good practice in unit testing, what is the scenario?

```
@Injectable()
export class FacultiesService {
  constructor(
    private apiService: ApiService,
    private dialog: MatDialog) { }


  openAddFacultyDialog(data = null) {
    const dialogRef = this.dialog.open(CreateEditComponent, {
      width: '400px',
      data
    });
    return dialogRef.afterClosed();
}

  createFaculty(faculty: Faculty) {
    return this.apiService.createEntity('Faculty', faculty);

  }
}

 @Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})

export class ApiService {
  constructor(private http: HttpClient) { }

  createEntity(entity: string, payload): Observable<any> {
    return this.http.post(`${this.apiURI}${entity}/insertData`, payload);
  }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The key thing to keep in mind while doing unit testing is that you should always test a functionality in isolation.

If you want to test the `FacultiesService` in your scenario, then the other services should be spied or mocked.

```js
// you can pass data using this mockMatDialog
const mockMatDialog = {}
let apiServiceSpy = jasmine.createSpyObj('ApiService', ['createEntity']);
beforeEach(() => {
  TestBed.configureTestingModule({
    providers: [{
        provide: ApiService,
        useValue: apiServiceSpy
      },
      {
        provide: MatDialog,
        useValue: mockMatDialog,
      },
    ]
  });
});

// If you want to get data from this spy observable use the following // syntax

apiServiceSpy.createEntity.and.returnValue(of({name: 'dummy data'}))
```

**UPDATE FOR NEW QUERY**

Yes, you can pass data which actual service returned like `createEntity`. I mean you can pass any data required for testing that fulfills you criteria. You should not check URL or method of http request because they are not part of this service. But in service you can test whether `createEntity()` method of apiservice is called and with what parameters.

like

```
expect(apiServiceSpy.createEntity).toHaveBeenCalled();
OR
// you can get most recent calls to this method
expect(apiServiceSpy.createEntity.calls.mostRecent()).
OR
// you can check the arguments passed to createEntity method as well
expect(apiServiceSpy.createEntity.calls.allArgs())
```

Comment: Should i have inject into providers FacultiesService? Because i got an error `No provider for FacultiesService!`

Comment: Yes definitely, i just gave you an example of mocking. if you want then i can update.

Comment: if i create more methods in apiService, I also need to specify here?
`let apiServiceSpy = jasmine.createSpyObj('ApiService', ['createEntity','updateEntity',...]);`

Comment: Yes, you need to specify the same way as mentioned by you. This is easiest way to spy all methods in a service(dependency).

Comment: What's the difference between to spy all methods and return some data and subscribe on Observalbe? Because in method **returnValue** we just paste random data. What if i want to paste an object in **createEntity**  and check do i get the same object. Or what if i want to check the URL of http request? or Method http request?

Comment: Updated my answer for your query, if you need more assistance we can chat.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/208513/discussion-between-jasdeep-singh-and-roni-droni).